# How to avoid Option.get and pattern match on None for Option that is always Some?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have this bit of (meta) code which deals with a database object I want to update `T`.

Only things known are the `ID` of such object, the `query` to retrieve it, and the `update` to perform.

```
def updateObject(...) : Either[(Int,String),(Int,T)] = {

    T.update(
      query,
      update,
    ) match {

    case 0 => Left(404, "No such object!")
    case _ =>
        T.findOne("id == objectId")
        .map((200, _)) match {
          case Some(result) => Right(result)
          case _ => ???
        }

  }

}
```

`T.update` performs an update on objects that satisfy `query` and returns a write result, which is an integer (number of records affected by the update).

Return type is `Either[(Int,String),(Int,T)]`:

- Left is meant to be a tuple with this format: (error_code, error_message).
- Right's format is this instead: (status_code, updated_object).

If numbers of affected records is 0, the object doesn't exists, hence I return a `Left(404,"No such object")`.

If the object has been updated, I need to fetch it (as I only have its id), map it to a `(Int,T)` and then return it in a `Right`.

**Here's the question**:

`T.findOne` returns `Option[T]`.

I've already performed an update on the object, therefore it exists and the result will always be `Some(T)`.

I know that `case _ => ???` will never be called, but the compiler will warn me of the match not being exhaustive if I don't put that in.

Is there a better way to deal with this (with `Option` that is always guaranteed to be `Some`)?

(I'm trying to avoid `Option.get` method), and `case _ => ???` seems like unnecessary and confusing code.

Comment: It seems like there's an extreme edge case where the object can be deleted after you've updated it, and before you retrieve it again. Why not just use another error code of your own for that case?

Comment: I was doing that, but then I realised that it's a "more-than-extreme" edge case. Previous code was: `T.findOne("id == objectId").map((200, _)).toRight(500, "Object has been deleted")`

Comment: You don't need to do match on an option. You can just do T.findOne("id == objectId").get which will throw an exception if the result is not a Some

Comment: @LionelPort "I'm trying to avoid Option.get method" (it's not a good  pattern)

Comment: @Matteo Pcini "it's not a good pattern" - could you please provide some reference, why it isn't

Comment: If you don't care about the extreme edge case, then use `.get`. However you decide to ignore `None` will result in an exception, so you might as well just use it.

Comment: @Tjunkie It's not the most idiomatic way to treat an Option, and on top of that it throws an exception. Pattern match isn't great too (the most idiomatic way would be treating the option as a collection or a monad e.g. `flatMap`, `foreach`, etc...), but it's still better than `.get`.

Comment: @MatteoPacini "it is not a good pattern" because it ignores the possibility of the Option being `None`, which is exactly what you are looking to do. In general, you can say "it's not a very idiomatic way" to apply your "meta knowledge" about it "being guaranteed to never be None" to something that is an `Option`. Re. "on top of that it throws an exception" ... that's "guaranteed" to never happen in your case, isn't it? :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have answered my own question using @m-z suggestion.

Comment: @MatteoPacini I should have mentioned getOrElse explicitly, because when you say "get" I kinda assume you are including the getOrElse with it as both being undesirable. I don't see how getOrElse could be a problem. And to my limited scala experience getOrElse seems easier to understand than "toRight".

Answer (score 1):

1st why not Option.get, if you are 100% sure there will be a result.
2nd Option.getOrElse will also cover the extreme edge case where the updated object disappeared before you were able to retrieve it.

How about something like this:

```
    T.findOne("id == objectId").map(Right(200,_._2)).getOrElse(Left(404,"Insane Corner Case : Updated Object not found"))
```

Comment: Look at my answer below. `map` can be written as `map((200,_))`, and then you can invoke `toRight`, which is an `Option` method.

Comment: sure you could, I've never seen toRight before. And now that I've read its scaladoc, I don't think I've missed anything elegant. It reads backwards: the thing that you supply as the argument is definitely not the "right" but the "left" - backwards :)  , whereas "getOrElse" seems very natural.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to consider the "extreme" case.

Code has been refactored to:

```
T
.findOne("id == objectId")
.map((200, _))
.toRight(404, "Object has been deleted")
```

Thanks to **m-z** for the tip.